# Server is not coming up when we configure HTTPS in wildfly 17 <socket-binding https="management-https"/> under management-interfaces

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I am facing one issue when i am trying to use Management Interfaces for HTTPS , wildfly not able to deploy the wars and its stopped but when i changed to http its working fine.

you can refer the configuration which i did in standalone.xml file.
Below tag i added in the management .

```
<management-interfaces>
<http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealmHTTPS">
    <http-upgrade enabled="true"/>
    <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
</http-interface>
```

I added the security realm under security-realms.

```
<security-realm name="ManagementRealmHTTPS">
<server-identities>
    <ssl>
        <keystore path="keystore" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="Ivr@123"/>
    </ssl>
</server-identities>
<authentication>
    <properties path="https-mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
</authentication>
```

and below is the socket-binding group config.

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
    <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

After doing all this config server is not coming up.
Its giving the below logs.

```
    =========================================================================
  JBoss Bootstrap Environment
  JBOSS_HOME: /tmp/wildfly-17.0.0.Final
  JAVA: /opt/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java
  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
=========================================================================
08:15:17,354 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.9.1.Final
08:15:17,869 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.7.Final
08:15:17,899 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
08:15:18,075 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 17.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 9.0.1.Final) starting
08:15:19,291 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 21) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.9.1.Final
08:15:20,013 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:15:20,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 6) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
08:15:20,160 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0040: Creating http management service using secure-socket-binding (management-https)
08:15:20,190 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO version 3.7.2.Final
08:15:20,205 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-8) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.7.2.Final
08:15:20,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
08:15:20,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.7.0.Final
08:15:20,319 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 8 core threads with 64 task threads based on your 4 available processors
08:15:20,337 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
08:15:20,339 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.16.Final)
08:15:20,350 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYMETRICS0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Metrics Subsystem
08:15:20,367 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.config.smallrye._private] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCONF0001: Activating WildFly MicroProfile Config Subsystem
08:15:20,375 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
08:15:20,395 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
08:15:20,395 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
08:15:20,442 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
08:15:20,455 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.opentracing] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYTRACEXT0001: Activating MicroProfile OpenTracing Subsystem
08:15:20,469 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
08:15:20,440 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.health.smallrye] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYHEALTH0001: Activating Eclipse MicroProfile Health Subsystem
08:15:20,475 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
08:15:20,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
08:15:20,532 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
08:15:20,544 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 2.0.21.Final starting
08:15:20,555 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.3.Final
08:15:20,619 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.12.Final
08:15:20,663 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-6) Converted [2] config entries and added [4] replacements
08:15:20,840 INFO  [io.smallrye.metrics] (MSC service thread 1-6) Converted [3] config entries and added [14] replacements
08:15:20,920 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path '/tmp/wildfly-17.0.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
08:15:20,945 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
08:15:20,949 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 64 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
08:15:21,096 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
08:15:21,101 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
08:15:21,271 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
08:15:21,516 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYPAT0050: WildFly Full cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
08:15:21,526 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
08:15:21,661 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
08:15:21,747 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
08:15:21,854 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.3.0.Final (Apache CXF 3.3.2)
08:15:21,945 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
08:15:21,946 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8443
08:15:21,963 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
08:15:21,967 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
08:15:21,968 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
08:15:21,971 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
08:15:21,989 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
08:15:22,006 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.0.21.Final stopping
08:15:22,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
08:15:22,051 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
08:15:22,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 17.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 9.0.1.Final) stopped in 20ms
```

Answer (score 0):

The worst part of this is that there isn't an error associated with it. I stumbled into the problem after changing one line at a time to match a Wildfly-16.0.0_Final server. The rest of the configuration seems to be working as expected, but as soon as you change to "socket-binding https="management-https"" the server breaks and refuses to come up. Does anyone know if this has been deprecated to force a move to Elytron SSL configuration?